# Disabled my camera app. Can't find it anymore!

Tags: camera

I disabled the camera app on my phone because the front-facing camera wasn't working. I had intended to re-enable it in a minute or two but when I went to my home screen it was not there, and it wasn't in the setting-all apps place either. I went to the play store and did not find the same camera that was previously on my phone either. Where did it go and how can I get it back??

Comment: What type of phone do you have? Was it the original camera app that came as default on your phone when you got it?

Answer (score 4):

Open `Settings> Apps> Disabled`& find the Camera app. You can enable it there. This is the common way to enable disabled apps on all android phones. Comment if any problem persists.

Comment: I'd like to add that if you try this method but you see the camera as enabled, disable it and enable it once again.You should see your camera after that.